# How to represent List of Strings in Springdoc Swagger v3?

Tags: springdoc, swagger-3.0

Below is a code that is similar to the situation I have

```java
@ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "OK", content = {@Content(schema = @Schema(
                implementation =  // <-- What to specify here?
            ))})
})
@GetMapping(value = "/user")
public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getUsers() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(Arrays.asList(new User(), new User()));
}
```

How do I specify the list of Users being returned from the endpoint in `ApiResponse()`?

Please note that the Open-API-Definition is not part of the project, but is specified in another project.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solved using the below method

```java
@ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "OK", content = {
                @Content(array = @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(implementation = User.class)))
            })
})
@GetMapping(value = "/user")
public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getUsers() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(Arrays.asList(new User(), new User()));
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to add a pattern to the List<String>? I tried to do @Schema(implementation = User.class, pattern = "pattern"), but it doesn't get generated in the swagger documents.

Comment: I'm not following what pattern you're referring to.